# Activate a minimized winform in Citrix via user32 functions

Tags: c#, citrix, user32

Has anyone ever had an issue running a C# Winforms app in Citrix using user32 functions when activating a minimized non-modal form?

What I'm attempting to do is within the activate event of a nonmodal form, check to see if there is a modal form available, and if so, bring it to the foreground and activate it.

Due to system constraints with our App, I cannot use Application.OpenForms to detect what types of forms are available (or use any of the form properties to activate or set windowstate to a form), so i'm using the User32 methods GetWindow & SetActiveWindow (or SetForegroundWindow) and using the MainWindowHandle value of the Application to determine the handle of the Modal form, bring it to the foreground and activate it.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 wCmd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, UInt32 uFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 wCmd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Text = "Form1";
            var nonModalButton = new Button() { Text = "Open non-modal window", Width = 200, Height = 30, Top = 10, Left = 10 };
            var modalButton = new Button() { Text = "Open modal window", Width = 200, Height = 30, Top = 50, Left = 10 };
            UInt32 GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6;

            // click event for modalButton
            modalButton.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                var modalWindow = new Form() { Text = "Modal Window"};
                var newModalWindowButton = new Button() { Text = "Open child modal window", Width = 200, Height = 30, Top = 50, Left = 10 };
                // add click event to newModalWindowButton to show as a modal
                newModalWindowButton.Click += (s1, e1) => { (new Form() { Text = "Child Modal Window" }).ShowDialog(); };
                // add to list of controls for modalWindow Form
                modalWindow.Controls.Add(newModalWindowButton);
                // open new ModalWindow as a modal form
                modalWindow.ShowDialog((IWin32Window)s);
                //modalWindow.ShowDialog();
            };
            // click event for non-modalButton
            nonModalButton.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                var nonModalWindow = new Form() { Text = "Non-Modal Window" };
                var newModalWindowButton = new Button() { Text = "Test", Width = 200, Height = 30, Top = 50, Left = 10 };
                nonModalWindow.Controls.Add(newModalWindowButton);
                // when non-modalWindow form is activated, find any active modal windows and activate the last one in the form collection
                nonModalWindow.Activated += (sender, ev) =>
                {
                    Form nonModalForm = sender as Form;
                    if (!nonModalForm.CanFocus)
                    {
                        var mainWindowHandlePtr = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

                        var modalPopupPtr = GetWindow(mainWindowHandlePtr, GW_ENABLEDPOPUP);
                        var NewPtr = SetActiveWindow(modalPopupPtr);

                        if (NewPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            SetForegroundWindow(modalPopupPtr);
                        }
                    }
                };
                nonModalWindow.Show((IWin32Window)s);
            };
            this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { modalButton, nonModalButton });
            this.Show();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

If i run this as an exe OUTSIDE the bounds of citrix with these steps:
    1) open a nonmodal form by clicking on the "open non-modal window" button
    2) minimize the nonmodal form
    3) open a modal form by clicking the "Open Modal Window" button 
    4) activate the non-modal form by clicking on the icon in the toolbar

The above code will bring the modal form to the foreground and the nonmodal form will be behind it. I've also noticed the newPtr value (the result of  SetActiveWindow) is the handle of the NonModalForm.

If i run this exe WITHIN citrix, with the same steps, the non-modal form remains in the foreground, and the value of newPtr is 0.

If the non-modal form is not minimized, and I attempt to activate it, then the modal form is brought to the foreground.

Is the a better (recommended) way to get these steps to work within Citrix?  Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: That's a pretty quirky snippet.  It looks to me like a workaround for a bug, the Show() and ShowDialog() calls try to make a button the parent of a form.  That can't work, it has to be a toplevel window.  Not exactly sure what happens next, but fairly sure that the OS simply ignores it and don't give the window a parent.  That causes Z-order problems.  Make a form the parent and you probably don't need this anymore.